# Intentional parallels between Little Sisters of Eluria and Wolves of the Calla?

Tags: vampire, stephen-king, the-dark-tower

In the *Dark Tower* short story *The Little Sisters of Eluria*, Roland encounters a stray dog with an injured leg and a patch of fur on his chest that is shaped like a cross.  The dog eventually attacks a vampire, and is successful because of the cross on his chest.

In the *Dark Tower* novel *Wolves of the Calla* (written about 7 years after *The Little Sisters of Eluria*), Roland meets a priest named Pere Callahan.  On Callahan's forehead is a scar shaped like a cross;  one of his hands is scarred from a burn he suffered in another Stephen King book, *'Salem's Lot*.  Callahan explains that he had gotten in trouble with evil beings called Low Men after he began killing vampires in New York City.  He was forced to flee the city after he started seeing "lost dog" signs inquiring about an "Irish Setter" with a scarred paw and scarred forehead;  he was smart enough to realize that the signs referred to himself.

The parallels are clear, intentional or otherwise:  dog with injured limb and the mark of the cross attacking vampires;  man with injured limb and the mark of the cross and who is explicitly referred to as a dog attacking vampires.

### Is this similarity intentional or coincidental?

Comment: My guess would be intentional. Everything in King's works seem to relate to something else.